# AotPlugin - Error: AppModule is not an NgModule

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Configuring AOT for my application in angular2, Getting this error,checked the paths everything is fine..

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of reasons and may be many more.. will update as I find them.

- typescript version error, Use version ***"2.0.10"***
- Check the path of the entry module in your **webpack.config** and
  **tsconfig** file

Comment: Changing typescript version from 2.1 back to 2.0.10 fixed this for me